# Where I can find Pattern Maker tool in PS CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

In previous versions there was Pattern Maker tool to create patterns out of graphics and photos. This feature is not available anymore under `Filter -> Pattern Maker...` in Photoshop CS6.

It was removed? If so, where I can find it now?

---

I'm asking, because there is [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWEOrzYM5HU) how to make patterns out of the photographs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/plug-ins-photoshop-cs61.html#id_18512):

> Plug-ins no longer supported in Photoshop CC and CS6
>
> • Variations
>   • Picture Package (ContactSheetII)
>   • ExtractPlus
>   • **PatternMaker**
>   • PhotomergeUI
>   • Web Photo Gallery (WebContactSheetII) plus presets
>   • Script for Layer Comps to Web Photo Gallery
>   • Texture presets for Texturizer